# How to get the name of first and last section of a chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I want to get the name of the first and the last section of a chapter to be printed into the table of contents for each chapter individually. Therefore I want to use the `etoc`-package. In the `etoc`-documentation in section 32.4. a macro is described, which they use to print a statistic for a chapter. I want to derive this, so the TOC is printed like that:

```
Table of Contents
Chapter 1  Chaptername
<Name of first Section> to <Name of last Section>
Chapter 2  Chaptername
etc
```

My knowledge isn't good enough for this, i don't understand the macros. Any way, that someone could help me or should I abandon this idea?

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,
    12pt,
    ]{book}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*answer edited to handle case of empty chapters, and use `\etociffirst` conditional from `etoc 1.08` or later.*

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,
    12pt,
    ]{book}
% This is commented out to compile with pdflatex:
%    \usepackage{luaotfload}
%    \usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{etoc}

% here some empty definitions to get a warning in case we 
% overwrite already existing macros from class or packages
\newcommand*\firstsectionname   {}  
\newcommand*\firstsectionnumber {}
\newcommand*\firstsectionpage   {}

% auxiliary command, to be executed from within the etoc user-defined
% section style
\newcommand*\storefirstsectiondata {%
         \let\firstsectionname  \etocthelinkedname
         \let\firstsectionnumber\etocthelinkednumber
         \let\firstsectionpage  \etocthelinkedpage
         }%

% A boolean to handle the case of chapters with no sections.
% To handle booleans in a more LaTeX way, use rather etoolbox package.
\newif\ifchapterhadnosections

% The definition of special Table of contents as per Question's request

% standard \tableofcontents not modified and can also be used
% independently

\newcommand*{\mytableofcontents}{%
  % our definitions are made inside a temporary group
  \begingroup 
  % chapter style
  % \etociffirst conditional requires etoc version 1.08 or later
  \etocsetstyle{chapter}
    {}
    {\etociffirst 
       {% first chapter, no extra vertical spacing should be added yet.
       }
       {% not the first chapter, check if previous one had no sections
       \ifchapterhadnosections
           This chapter contains no sections.\par
       \fi
       % let's add always some vertical spacing
       \addvspace{1em}}%
    }
    {\noindent\makebox[6em][l]{Chapter~\etocnumber}%
     \textbf{\etocname}\par
     % boolean which will be set to false by first encountered section
     \chapterhadnosectionstrue
    }
    {\ifchapterhadnosections % this code is executed after the last chapter
           This chapter contains no sections.\par
     \fi
    }
  % section style
  \etocsetstyle{section} 
    {\chapterhadnosectionsfalse } 
    {\etociffirst{\storefirstsectiondata}{}}
    {}
    {% this piece of the section style is the one executed 
     % after the last section of the current chapter has been seen
     \firstsectionname{} (on page \firstsectionpage) 
       to 
     % \etocname, \etocnumber, \etocpage currently contain
     % the name, number, page number, of the last section
     % of the enveloping chapter
     \etocname{} (on page \etocpage)%
     \par
     }% 
   %
  \etocsetnexttocdepth {section}%
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}

\usepackage{hyperref}% to test the links

\begin{document}
\mytableofcontents

\chapter{ALPHA}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage
\section{Section 3}

\chapter{BETA}
\section{Section 4}
\clearpage
\section{Section 5}

\chapter{GAMMA}

\chapter{DELTA}
\section{Section 6}
\clearpage
\section{Section 7}

\chapter{Final chapter (with no sections)}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: special toc]

Earlier answer:

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,
    12pt,
    ]{book}
% commented out to compile with pdflatex
%\usepackage{luaotfload}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand*\firstsectionname   {}  
\newcommand*\firstsectionnumber {}
\newcommand*\firstsectionpage   {}
\newcommand*\lastsectionname   {}  
\newcommand*\lastsectionnumber {}
\newcommand*\lastsectionpage   {}
\newcommand*\storefirstsectiondata {}

\newcommand*{\mytableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
  \etocsetstyle{chapter}
    {\etocskipfirstprefix}
    {\addvspace{1em}}
    {\noindent\makebox[6em][l]{Chapter~\etocnumber}%
     \textbf{\etocname}\par}
    {}
  %
  \etocsetstyle{section} 
    {\def\storefirstsectiondata{%
         \let\firstsectionname  \etocthelinkedname
         \let\firstsectionnumber\etocthelinkednumber
         \let\firstsectionpage  \etocthelinkedpage
         \let\storefirstsectiondata\empty
         }%
     } 
    {}
    {\storefirstsectiondata
     \let\lastsectionname  \etocthelinkedname
     \let\lastsectionnumber\etocthelinkednumber 
     \let\lastsectionpage  \etocthelinkedpage}
    {\firstsectionname{} (on page \firstsectionpage) 
       to 
     \lastsectionname{} (on page \lastsectionpage)%
     \par
     }% 
   %
   \etocsetnexttocdepth {1}%
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}


\usepackage{hyperref}% to test the links
\begin{document}
\mytableofcontents

\chapter{ALPHA}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage
\section{Section 3}

\chapter{BETA}
\section{Section 4}
\clearpage
\section{Section 5}

\chapter{GAMMA}

\chapter{DELTA}
\section{Section 6}
\clearpage
\section{Section 7}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: table of contents first to last section per chapter]

The unnecessarily complex code of the initial answer (gives same output as above).

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,
    12pt,
    ]{book}
% commented out to compile with pdflatex
%\usepackage{luaotfload}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand*\firstsectionname   {}  
\newcommand*\firstsectionnumber {}
\newcommand*\firstsectionpage   {}
\newcommand*\lastsectionname   {}  
\newcommand*\lastsectionnumber {}
\newcommand*\lastsectionpage   {}
\newcommand*\storefirstsectiondata {}
\newcommand*\previouschaptername {}
\newcommand*\previouschapternumber {}
\newcommand*\previouschapterpage {}
\newif\ifpreviouschapterhassections

\newcommand*{\mytableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
  \etocsetstyle{chapter}
    {\etocskipfirstprefix}
    {\ifpreviouschapterhassections
     \else
       \noindent\makebox[6em][l]{Chapter~\previouschapternumber}%
       \textbf{\previouschaptername}\par
     \fi
     \addvspace{1em}
    }
    {\let\previouschaptername  \etocthelinkedname
     \let\previouschapternumber\etocthelinkednumber
     \let\previouschapterpage  \etocthelinkedpage
     \previouschapterhassectionsfalse
    }
    {\ifpreviouschapterhassections % only if last chapter of document has no sections
     \else
       \noindent\makebox[6em][l]{Chapter~\previouschapternumber}%
       \textbf{\previouschaptername}\par
     \fi
    }
  %
  \etocsetstyle{section} 
    {\def\storefirstsectiondata{%
         \let\firstsectionname  \etocthelinkedname
         \let\firstsectionnumber\etocthelinkednumber
         \let\firstsectionpage  \etocthelinkedpage
         \let\storefirstsectiondata\empty
         }%
     } 
    {}
    {\storefirstsectiondata
     \let\lastsectionname  \etocthelinkedname
     \let\lastsectionnumber\etocthelinkednumber 
     \let\lastsectionpage  \etocthelinkedpage}
    {\previouschapterhassectionstrue 
     \noindent\makebox[6em][l]{Chapter~\previouschapternumber}%
     \textbf{\previouschaptername}\par
       \firstsectionname{} (on page \firstsectionpage) 
       to 
       \lastsectionname{} (on page \lastsectionpage)%
     \par
     }% 
   %
   \etocsetnexttocdepth {1}%
  \previouschapterhassectionsfalse
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}

\usepackage{hyperref}% to test the links
\begin{document}
\mytableofcontents

\chapter{ALPHA}
\section{Section 1}
\clearpage
\section{Section 2}
\clearpage
\section{Section 3}

\chapter{BETA}
\section{Section 4}
\clearpage
\section{Section 5}

\chapter{GAMMA}

\chapter{DELTA}
\section{Section 6}
\clearpage
\section{Section 7}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This is like exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option, using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) and [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\gdef\firstsection{}
\gdef\lastsection{}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\makeatletter
\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {%
    \ifnum\value{section}=1\relax\gdef\firstsection{#1}\fi%
    \gdef\lastsection{#1}#1%
  }

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\relax\else
    \ifnum\value{section}>1\relax
      \protect\addtocontents{toc}{\firstsection~to~\lastsection\par}
    \fi
  \fi}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\value{section}>1\relax
    \protect\addtocontents{toc}{\firstsection~to~\lastsection\par}
  \fi  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{Test section one one}
\section{Test section one two}
\section{Test section one three}

\chapter{Another test chapter}
\section{Test section two one}
\section{Test section two two}
\section{Test section two three}
\section{Test section two four}

\chapter{A test chapter without sections}

\chapter{A last test chapter}
\section{Test section three one}
\section{Test section three two}
\section{Test section three three}
\section{Test section three four}
\section{Test section three five}
\section{Test section three six}

\chapter{Another test chapter without sections}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. With your MWE it is working, with my rather complex document I get a tripled section-entry on the last chapter.